# How to show tooltip in chrome and safari browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to display the tooltip for dropdownlist in my web application its displaying in IE and Mozilla but in Google Chrome and Safari its not displaying.

```
Select.options[i].title= oObject.Text;
```

its how i bind using javascript

Comment: Do you expect us to know what code etc you are using? **Please show us some code!**

Answer (score 0):

Can't help much with the code you posted. Are you using a plugin, script or what? If you're using jquery you can always use a plugin, this one for exemple http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ works pretty good.

Remember that you can always just set the title attribute for the tag, browsers will interpret it as a tooltip. Example:

```
<select title="Link tooltip">
    <option>Option1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is not valid and should throw complication error.

Assuming the ID of your drop down list is `Select1` here is the way to set the title of its different options via the code behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Select1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Select1.Items[i].Attributes["title"] = "I am item #" + (i + 1);
}
```